# Probabilities involving sampling from a distribution

Tags: probability-limit-theorems

I've this problem, to compute the probabilities of a normal distribution

Fifty-seven percent of students at Calabria Business School support making Introduction to Philanthropy a required course. The school plans to survey 100 students to gauge opinion on this issue. What is the probability that no more than half of those surveyed will say they support requiring the course?

My issue, I don't see how to get the mean.
I've 
Pop.Sample_size = 100
P(Z<0.5)
We know 0.57 support the required course.
Any clues are welcome

Comment: Not sure the problem is clear.  If there are exactly $100$ students in the school, then the answer is $0$.  Presumably they don't mean situations like that, so I guess they want you to assume that there are so many students that you can treat each student as an independent even, in which case this is a routine binomial distribution problem.  But, really, that's the sort of assumption that needs to be stated explicitly.

Comment: Not clear to me too. But I'm sure should be solved using normal distribution probabilities.

Comment: Well, under my assumption (which I assume is the one they want you to make) there is no difficulty computing the exact answer.  Of course, you can use the standard normal approximation to the binomial to estimate the result (should be a pretty good estimate).

Comment: Worth noting:  even if you assume there are, say, $2000$ students in the school, the exact answer is quite far off of the "idealized" answer (assuming a very large number of students).  Whoever set the problem really ought to have specified what assumptions are being made.

Comment: @lulu Don´t we have to calculate $P(X\leq 50)$, where $X\sim Bin(100,0.75)$? And I don´t see a problem in approximating the binominal distribution since $n=100$

Comment: I've found this link with a similar question, but I don't get the good results even when just plugging the values https://www.dummies.com/education/math/statistics/how-to-find-probabilities-for-a-sample-proportion/

Comment: @CarlosCarvalho The probability tends to $0$

Comment: #callculus I thought that too, but the result must be between .0058 and .0096

Comment: @CarlosCarvalho Why it is an interval? Maybe this is the result to another question.

Comment: I don't say the result is an interval, I mean the result should be between those values, wheter .058, or .096, or .079, .082 this  is given,  now, which one is correct?

Comment: You can see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(k%3D0)%5E50+(100+choose+k)*0.75%5Ek*0.25%5E(100-k)) what the output of the calculator is. It is very close to 0.

Comment: But this is a Normal distribution

Comment: Really? When I was reading the exercise it seemed to me that the binomial distribution would be the appropriate distribution. Then I have no further ideas.

Comment: @CarlosCarvalho I notice that you use both fifty-seven and 0.75. It seems harder to make an error of spelling out the wrong number so do you mean 0.57?

Comment: @callculus  I don't understand the question you asked me (several comments back).  Why Bin$(100,.75)$?  Under the assumption I am making, we'd want Bin$(100,.57)$.  Where does the $.75$ come from?

Comment: I also don't understand the bit about the intervals.  If you specify a range of the number of students, then of course you'd get a range for the answer, but nothing like that has been specified.

Comment: Sorry, It's .57

Comment: @CarlosCarvalho When you specify options are you suggesting that the answer is multiple choice?

Comment: No, It's only one choice, But I got it, it's .0793
i was plugging the number wrongly, following same logique as https://www.dummies.com/education/math/statistics/how-to-find-probabilities-for-a-sample-proportion/

Comment: #callculus your site is great https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(k%3D0)%5E50+(100+choose+k)*0.75%5Ek*0.25%5E(100-k)

Answer (score 1):

Since the discussion in the comments has gotten a bit involved, I thought I'd post something here.

As discussed in the comments, the problem is missing critical information.  If the number of students, $S$, is low then we need to know what $S$ is.  For instance, if $S=100$ then the answer is $0$ since we know that $57$ students support the choice.

For a general $S$, we'd have $.57\times S$ supporters, leaving $.43\times S$ non-supporters.  In that case the answer we want would be $$P_S=\frac {\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{50}\binom {.57\times S}i\times \binom {.43\times S}{100-i}}{\binom {S}{100}}$$

Where the binomial symbols are set to $0$ when the denominator is $<0$.

For instance,$P_{100}=.07143$ and  $P_{1000}= .0836$.

Now, if $S$ is very large we can safely assume that each student independently has a $.57$ probability of being a supporter.  In that case the exact answer is given by the binomial distribution:  $$\sum_{i=0}^{50}\binom {100}i\times .57^i\times .43^{100-i}=.095$$

Note that even with $S=1000$ we're quite far from this value.  Even $P_{5000}=.09124$ which is still a bit off of the limiting value.

We could get an approximate answer by using the normal approximation to the answer.  The mean for the normal is $57$ and $\sigma = \sqrt {100\times .57\times .43}=4.95$  Using that data, we compute the probability that a random value drawn from the distribution is $≤50.5$ and get $.0946$ which is pretty close to the limiting value.  Note that the $50.5$ includes the so-called continuity correction.

Comment: Thanks for doing the leg work around this!